# Casting custom Matrix to float*

Tags: c++, matrix, directx, directx-11

So I've been writing my own physics engine off and on for a while now and I recently started setting up DirectX rendering instead of hardcoding in my rendering with OpenGL. Now, at the very end, I've come across what seems to be some very bizarre behavior that I cannot figure out.

In order to pass Matrices to a shader to draw things, you call a function that takes a `const float*` and the typical way to do this is to pass in a `D3DXMATRIX` cast to `float*`. `D3DXMATRIX` and the cast operators are declared as:

```
typedef struct D3DXMATRIX : public D3DMATRIX
{
    ...
    operator FLOAT* ();
    operator CONST FLOAT* () const;
    ....
} D3DXMATRIX, *LPD3DMATRIX;
```

and `D3DMATRIX` is declared as:

```
typedef struct _D3DMATRIX {
    union {
        struct {
            float    __11, _12, _13, _14;
            float    __21, _22, _23, _24;
            float    __31, _32, _33, _34;
            float    __41, _42, _43, _44;
        };
        float m[4][4];
    };
} D3DMATRIX;
```

The two casting operators are defined in a different file (D3DX10math.inl) as:

```
D3DX10INLINE
D3DXMATRIX::operator FLOAT* ()
{
    return (FLOAT *) &_11;
}

D3DX10INLINE
D3DXMATRIX::operator CONST FLOAT* () const
{
    return (CONST FLOAT *) &_11;
}
```

The `CONST` and `FLOAT` keywords are defined in `minwindef.h` and `D3DX10INLINE` is defined in D3DX10.h as:

```
#ifndef CONST
#define CONST const
#endif
....
typedef float FLOAT;
....
#define D3DX10INLINE __forceline
```

The call to the function I described is simply:

```
D3DXMATRIX m;
foo->SetMatrix((float*)&m);
```

Throughout my engine I have been using my own `Matrix` class, and when I attempt to pass it into the above function instead of a `D3DXMATRIX`, it sends incorrect data. My `Matrix` class is (seemingly) defined in the same way as `D3DXMATRIX`, but refuses to function the same way. Here is my matrix class (or the relevant parts):

```
class Matrix {
    public:
        ....
        operator float* ();
        operator const float* () const;
        ....
    private:
        union {
            struct {
                float _00, _01, _02, _03;
                float _10, _11, _12, _13;
                float _20, _21, _22, _23;
                float _30, _31, _32, _33;
            };
            float m[4][4];
        }
};
```

and the functions are define as:

```
__forceinline
Matrix::operator float* ()
{
    return (float *) &_00;
}

__forceinline
Matrix::operator const float* () const
{
    return (const float *) &_00;
}
```

I've tried defining the operators in the CPP file, in the header file, in the class definition, all with and without `inline` and `__forceinline`, but nothing will ever make it work. I suppose I could copy all the data in each of my matrices to a `D3DXMATRIX`, but that wastes a bunch of time/operations and *should* be irrelevant. The biggest issue is that I cannot for the life of my figure out why everything behaves this way. I cannot possibly see why.

To be sure of the data being passed into the DirectX function, I set up a test function so I can debug it and see what the exact values being passed in:

```
void Test(const float *a, const float *b)
{
    bool result[16] = {false};
    float aa[16], bb[16];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = a[i] == b[i];
        aa[i] = a[i];
        bb[i] = b[i];
    }
}
```

For example, if I pass in a `D3DXMATRIX` with the values `1-16` for each of the 16 floats as the first parameter one of my matrices with the same values as `b` then `aa` will be populated with the values `1-16` just fine, but `bb` will = `{0.0, 1.875, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.125, 0.0, 2.5, 0.0, 2.315, 0.0, 2.375, 0.0, 2.4375, 0.0, 2.5}`

So...anyone have any ideas why this code behaves this way?

Comment: Do you have any other member variables in `Matrix`?

Comment: @AntonSavin No, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually using `operator float*` incorrectly.

```
D3DXMATRIX m;
foo->SetMatrix((float*)&m);
```

Here you convert the *address* of `m` to `float*`. This isn't invoking `operator float`, it's a mere `reinterpret_cast` (and compiler should give a warning about that). But fortunately for you `D3DMATRIX` doesn't contain any other members and no padding at the beginning so everything works.

If `Matrix` contains other data members before its `_00` or is not [standard-layout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType) such conversion may produce indeterminate results.

So the bottomline is, you should do

```
foo->SetMatrix((float*)m);
```

or just

```
foo->SetMatrix(m);
```

Comment: There are no other data members in my Matrix class and there is absolutely no functional difference between foo->SetMatrix((float*)&m), foo->SetMatrix((float*)m) and foo->SetMatrix(m) at all.

Comment: @ArcRaizen Can you try `static_assert<std::is_standard_layout<Matrix>>::value`?

Comment: comes back as true

Comment: @ArcRaizen So you should provide a [mcve] otherwise one can only guess.